# Getting back into windows 10 normal boot (as opposed to safe boot) without being able to login

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, passwords, login

To troubleshoot a problem I used msconfig to set that windows 10 should boot without loading most of the services (safe boot). I rebooted the PC and then noticed that I could not login with the PIN in safe mode. Its my father's laptop and he doesn't remember the original password of his account.

Because I can not login I can not tell windows to start booting in normal mode again. Is there any way to let windows boot in normal mode without requiring me to login?

**What I did so far:**

- Created a windows 10 installation usb drive
- Booted from the usb drive and followed a trick I found online to rename c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe to c:\windows\system32\utilman.exe (after backing up utilman.exe). This allows me to access a command prompt when logging in from the harddisk again by clicking the accessiblity icon on the login screen.
- I then created a new administrator account using:

*net user myusername /add*

and

*net localgroup administrators myusername /add*

I then rebooted and tried to login using that user, but I get an error when logging in saying: "The service User Profile Service prevents logging in. User profile cannot be loaded" (I translated that from dutch).

Does anyone have a solution? Maybe a file I can edit from the command prompt to tell windows to boot normally again?

Comment: Just log into the default built-in Administrator user.

Comment: As far as I know there is only one administrator account which was his own personal account of which he didn't know the password. I also doubt he knows the password of the default administrator account if it exists.

Comment: It is there by default.  All you do is enable it then log into it.  Unless he set a password to it and then forgot it, it shouldn't have a password, it should simply be disabled.  Before you ask, "but how do I enable it", you should make sure you have researched how to do it.

Comment: Reset the password using the command prompt...http://reboot.pro/topic/15751-reset-a-forgotten-windows-7-password-without-using-any-third-party-software-how-to-tutorial/